# FutureBuilder fails with an exception

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my stateful widget and flutter keeps throwing an exception and I don't know why.

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: FutureBuilder(
                future: createUser(),
                builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
                  switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
                    case ConnectionState.waiting:
                      return const Text('Creating Account....');
                    default:
                      if (snapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
                      } else {
                        return Home(json: snapshot.data);
                      }
                  }
                })));
  }
```

and the `Home` Widget:

```
  const Home({Key? key, required this.json}) : super(key: key);
  final String json;

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(widget.json);
  }
}
```

Everything looks okay but when I run the build, i get an exception:

```
type 'Response<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String'

The relevant error-causing widget was
FutureBuilder<dynamic>
```

This is the Create method:

```
Future createUser() async {
    final prefs = await sharedPref();
    final user = User((b) => b
      ..firstName = prefs.getString('firstName')
      ..lastName = prefs.getString('lastName')
      ..email = prefs.getString('email')
      ..profilePhotoUrl = prefs.getString('photo')
      ..isocode = prefs.getString('currency'));

    final userSerlizedObject = standardSerializers.serialize(user);
    final res = devHttpClient.post(
      '/createaccount',
      data: userSerlizedObject,
    );

    return res;
  }
```

What is causing this exception, I am having trouble finding why?

Comment: Show me createUser()

Comment: @BobLee I have updated the question with the create method

Comment: Could u update your code to GitHub?. Cos I need to understand your code to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your method `createUser()` returns a `Response<T>`.

When calling this method

```
return Home(json: snapshot.data);
```

You're casting a `Response<T>` in a `String` (since your `json` param is a String)

You should update your `createUser()` method in order to return the body of the response, and not the response itself

Answer (score -2):

just add .toString() to snapshot.data

return Home(json: snapshot.data.toString());